# Changing a nonlinear equality constraint into some conic inequality plus rank constraint

Tags: linear-algebra, convexity, convex-optimization, global-optimization, nonlinear-optimization

If we have a constraint optimization problem in which one of our constraint is $\prod\limits_{k = 1}^N {\left( {x - {a_k}} \right) = 0} $ . How could this nonlinear equality condition be changed into a combination of some conic inequality constraint and rank constraint??

Comment: Let $A = diag(a_1, ..., a_N)$ and $I$ be the identity. Then, your constraint becomes $rank(xI - A) = 0$. No need for conic inequality constraints.